# How Do you pass options to the Java VM through a ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, servletcontextlistener

How do you go about specifying options to pass to the Java VM, such as what is used for `JAVA_OPTS` in JBoss' `standalone.conf`, in the code base through a class which implements `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`?

Comment: You don't. `JAVA_OPTS` are mostly options used during JVM initialization. By the time your `ServletContextListener` runs, the JVM is already initialized. --- Also, those options affect the entire JVM, and your webapp should not do things that affect other webapps running in the same JBoss instance.

Comment: @Andreas Can it not be done through a static block of code at the top of the class? If not, how can you specify options to pass to the JAVA VM, as `JAVA_OPTS` does, without specifically altering `standalone.conf`?

Comment: Before I can answer, what option are you trying to specify? As I already said, most options are JVM initialization options and cannot be specified after initialization has already completed. If you're referring to `-Dname=value` options, then they can be done using [`System.setProperty("name", "value")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) at any time, but I would highly discourage you from doing so, as it may affect other webapps too.

Comment: @Andreas I am trying to add a package to a jackson whitelist, after the recent [JBoss 6.4.20 patch][1], so in the `standalone.conf` it would be something along the lines of `-Djackson.deserialization.whitelist.packages=foo.bar.baz`. Could you elaborate a little more on why it is discouraged? This is the only webapp being deployed to this JBoss server, as far as I am aware, but I would like to understand your perspective a little more. [1]: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhsa-announce/2018-May/msg00028.html

Comment: If you *know* that your webapp is the only webapp, or is the only one using Jackson, then it's not an issue. But do you *know*? If not, do you understand what *unintended effect* setting the value would have on the other webapps?

Comment: @Andreas It is the only webapp, yes. I am not entirely sure of what potential _unintended effect_ could arise if it were not, however. Could you elaborate on the hypothetical?